# How to build and pass remap for floating point raster without getting Reclassify ERROR 010255?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst

I am receiving the following message when executing my python script:

> ERROR 010255: String remap must be used with a string field.

My input raster is floating point and I would like to reclassify it in python using **gp.Reclassify_sa**.

I build my remap up as a string, but this doesn't seem to work.

How do I build and pass my remap for a floating point raster?

The relevant code extract is as follows:

```
remap1 = "0 1.25 100000"
remap2 = "1.25 10 200000"
full_remap = remap1 + ";" + remap2
gp.Reclassify_sa(in_raster, "VALUE", full_remap, out_raster, "NODATA")
```

Comment: Would you be able to edit your ArcGIS for Desktop version into your question, please?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Help file for the Reclassify tool it looks like you have got the format of your remap wrong. In help the values are comma separated and are lists within lists fed into a function that creates a ReMap Table. I suggest you look at the [code samples](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000sr000000) at the end of the help page.